# How to fix "Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'". Date and Time

Tags: python, json

I am playing around with parsing data from a log file using python.
When i try to add date and time i dont have valid JSON any more..

Have been looking around and i dont se a formatting error or unicode problem

```py
import datetime


with open("messages", "r") as log_file:
    for line in log_file:
        line_list = line.split()

        log = {}
        # date = datetime.strptime(" ".join(line_list[:3]), '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
        # log['Date'] = date.replace(year=2019)  # no year in log
        log['Day'] = line_list[1]
        log['Time'] = line_list[2]
        # log["Month"] = datetime.strptime(
        #   " ".join(line_list[:3]), '%b %d %H:%M:%S').isoformat()
        log["Device"] = line_list[3]
        log["User_info"] = line_list[4]
        log["Message"] = " ".join(line_list[6:])

        logs.append(log)


print(logs)
```

Gives me:

```
{'Day': '8', 'Time': '16:48:38', 'Device': 'icmp-73260f', 'User_info': 'user.info', 'Message': 'SM- ADSP: SPORT resync counter: 0, state: playing'}, {'Day': '8', 'Time': '16:48:39', 'Device': 'icmp-73260f', 'User_info': 'user.info', 'Message': 'Player- received GIP input selection request: input 0'}
```

But pasting this in a JSON validator gives me:

Parse error on line 1:
[{'Day': '17', 'Time':
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

Comment: It's clear that there is an empty value in attribute `Time`.

Comment: Thank you,

Solved it by: log['Time'] = " ".join(line_list[:3])